# holographic projection in thin air?

Tags: optics, experimental-technology, hologram, technology

from where I come from ,they taught us in high school that it is possible to project holograms in thin air simply by illuminating the hologram with the "correct light" , and having a semi transparent medium in the path of the reflecting light "e.g. Water vapor or smoke" resulting in something like this image [image]

-is this true & if not is there any technology that can project such 3dImages in thin air ?

Comment: Holography can make such images appear in total vacuum. But you need a screen of some sort to make it happen. If there is a kind of gas or smoke around to project an image, then it is not an hologram, just light projection onto some material. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @fffred what they taught us seems to be the second case you are talking about "smoke" , but they told us that the projection appears 3d ,with different views for people looking from different angels.

Comment: One TV development back in 1930's had a screen less viewer that appeared to float in space. Like viewing an image reflected on a rotating fan blade. Mechanically it would work better in a vacuum. "Google Images" may help explain "Mirror Screw tv". In the 1930's there were limitations on turning a light on/off. LED's would not have that problem.

Comment: This may help http://www.televisionexperimenters.com/mirscrws.html

Comment: @fffred , both ideas are compatible, and there are differences between typical lens projections and holographic projections. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The car in the picture seems to be projected with the projector in the top (2D projection). A similar 3D static car image could be accomplished with a cylindrical hologram. Any hologram can be illuminated in an appropriate way ("the correct light") to build a *real image* besides a *virtual* one.

Then, if you put a screen inside it, you are going to see a low contrast (due to light converging in other planes) picture (a view) of the 3D holographed object. The point or difference with lens imaging, like the one due to a standard projector, is that this allows to project in many planes (one at each time, or at the same time with dust/fog), as there is 3D information.

If you use dust you may **project** a 3D image, also low contrast, because your 3D distribution of point-like sources of light has a background due to light focusing in other points and that pass through. You'll also see your object is *transparent*, as you are watching light coming from every point.

In 2D lens image projections, light focusing in other planes produce blur (points become discs).